# How do I globally configure XML parsers against XXE?

Tags: xml, security, web-applications

Parsing XML in Java has become very simple. Most of the code eventually calls `DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()` which returns an XML parser that is vulnerable to [XXE kind of attacks by default](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_%28XXE%29_Processing).

The OWASP document explains at length how to configure an XML parser returned from `DocumentBuilderFactory` to prevent this kind of attack but how can I make this the default?

My problem is that I'm using libraries like JDOM2 and other code which processes XML and I can't easily change all this code. How would I make a safe parser the default?

I've seen that `DocumentBuilderFactory` supports the `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory` but how does that work for web applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to write your customized DocumentBuilderFactory
and set system property for `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory`

So `DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()` will return your customized class

See documentation [DocumentsBuilderFactory#newInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newInstance())

**[EDIT]** Now this can cause problems with web containers like Tomcat which doesn't support System properties per webapp. The solution here is to set the property for the container and put the custom factory on the classpath of the server. That way, all webapps will use it - which is probably what you want for an important security feature like this one.

Comment: How does that work in a web application which shares the VM with other apps? Do I have to configure the whole VM or can I configure this somehow per app?

Answer (score 2):

See http://web-in-security.blogspot.fr/2014/11/detecting-and-exploiting-xxe-in-saml.html or https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_%28XXE%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

But following code is providing good protection

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
dbf.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");
dbf.setAttribute(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, Boolean.TRUE);
dbf.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
```

Not sure of the effect of XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING. It's often documented with dbf.setFeature but it's not available in all version of Xerces